# AnimatedRotation for animating compass

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

AnimatedRotation for animating compass

I am trying to add a compass to my app. What is the best way to animate the rotation from 359 to 0 or 0 to 359? Is there a better suited widget for this type of rotation?

```
AnimatedRotation(
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 250),
      turns: -heading / 360.0,
      curve: Curves.linear,
```

Tried to do it by adding the difference instead of assigning the angle but it can overflow if it is rotating on same direction.

```
if(previousHeading - heading > 180) {
  turns += ((360.0 - previousHeading) + heading) / 360.0;
}
else if(previousHeading - heading < -180) {
  turns -= ((360.0 - heading + previousHeading)) / 360.0;
}
else {
  turns += ((previousHeading - heading) / 360.0);
}

previousHeading = heading;
```

Comment: check `RotationTransition`

Answer (score 6):

Widget:

```
AnimatedRotation(
  turns: turns,
  duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 250),
  child: const Icon(Icons.arrow_upward_outlined),
)
```

To get the correct "turn" value you should do this:

```
double prevValue = 0.0;

FlutterCompass.events?.listen((CompassEvent event) {
  double? direction = event.heading;
  direction = direction < 0 ? (360 + direction): direction;

  double diff = direction - prevValue;
  if(diff.abs() > 180) {
    if(prevValue > direction) {
      diff = 360 - (direction-prevValue).abs();
    } else {
      diff = 360 - (prevValue-direction).abs();
      diff = diff * -1;
    }
  }
  turns += (diff / 360);
  prevValue = direction;
});
```

I hope this could save some time to others ;)

Answer (score 0):

Animated version of [Transform.rotate](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Transform/Transform.rotate.html) which automatically transitions the child's rotation over a given duration whenever the given rotation changes.

For Clear Analysis please check [here:](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AnimatedRotation-class.html)

Answer (score 0):

use smooth compass very easy to use, check here
https://pub.dev/packages/smooth_compass